# Unity 2D Camera Zooms in when character moves, but properties of the camera do not change

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, zooming

After I click play the camera stays as it should be, but when I move my character the camera zooms in for no reason

The properties of the camera do not change at all, zoom and everything stays the same. Tryed changing from orthographic to perspective no change, move z axis no change, change scale no change, change resolution and no change, making the camera not a parent and no change it behaves the same as parent and as child
[before character walks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V07Fv.png)

[after character walks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7wuc.png)

I dont think that there is something to do with the code but here is the code attached to my character, the camera behaves the same as child and as parent

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8f;
    private float movementX = 0f;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
    public Transform groundCheckPoint;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    public bool isTouchingGround;
    public SpriteRenderer box;

    private bool canSpawn = true;
    private bool canAnimateWalk = true;
    private bool canAnimateIdle = true;
    private bool canAnimateJump = true;
    private bool stopJump = true;
    private int spawningSpeed = 1000;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isTouchingGround = Physics2D.OverlapBox(groundCheckPoint.position,new Vector2(0.9f,0.1f),0f, groundLayer);
        movementX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (movementX > 0f)
        {
            if(canAnimateWalk==true && isTouchingGround)
            {
                canAnimateWalk = false;
                StartCoroutine(AnimateWalk());
            }

            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().transform.localScale = new Vector3(2, 2, 1);
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movementX * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (movementX < 0f)
        {
            if (canAnimateWalk == true && isTouchingGround)
            {
                canAnimateWalk = false;
                StartCoroutine(AnimateWalk());
            }
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().transform.localScale = new Vector3(-2, 2, 1);
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movementX * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }
        else
        {
            if(isTouchingGround)
            {
                StopCoroutine(AnimateWalk());

                if(canAnimateIdle==true)
                {
                    canAnimateIdle = false;
                    StartCoroutine(AnimateIdle());
                }

            }
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, rigidBody.velocity.y);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isTouchingGround)
        {
            canAnimateJump = false;
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x, jumpSpeed);
            StartCoroutine(AnimateJump());
        }
        else if(!isTouchingGround)
        {
            StopCoroutine(AnimateWalk());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AnimateJump()
    {
        Debug.Log("Animating Jump");
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < 10)
        {
            counter++;
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("img/j" + counter);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            if(isTouchingGround==true)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while(!isTouchingGround)
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("img/j10");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("img/i1");
        canAnimateWalk = true;
        canAnimateJump = true;
    }

    IEnumerator AnimateIdle()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")==0 && counter <10 && rigidBody.velocity.y==0)
        {
            counter++;
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("img/i"+counter);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        }
        canAnimateIdle = true;
    }
    IEnumerator AnimateWalk()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")!=0 && counter < 8 && rigidBody.velocity.y==0)
        {
            counter++;
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("img/g" + counter);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.08f);
        }

        canAnimateWalk = true;

    }
}
```

What could it be? I tried everything I think

Answer (score 1):

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().transform.localScale = new Vector3(-2, 2, 1);
```

If your movement script is attached to your "guy" gameobject, then you are changing the (local) scale of it. All children will also scale accordingly. 
Since your camera is a child of guy, it will scale and produce the result you see.

Try unparenting the Camera from your guy and create a seperate script that follows your guy and attach that to your Camera.

Comment: I mentioned that camera behaved the same way as parent and child, I found the solution though, I was changing the scale of my character, I had a different character that had 2,2 scale and I replaced it with 1 and 1 scale, and forgot to change it in code so when I walked my character became twice as large))

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem

The issue was in the character scaling. The camera did not change but the size of the character did making me believe that there was a zoom in.

My character x and y scale is 1 and 1 but I used 2 and 2 scale on move

The scale was used to rotate my character when it moves left and right